# How to push metric to Cortex directly

Tags: python, prometheus

Is there any way/client (python) to push metric to Cortex?
We have Prometheus which pushes metrics but in this case i need to set up project from which Prometheus could pull and then push to Cortex.

I need to avoid this and push metric directly to Cortex and skip Prometheus.

Answer (score 2):

Cortex supports data ingestion with [Prometheus remote_write API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write). There is an example Python code that prepares and sends data to remote storage over Prometheus remote_write API - see https://gist.github.com/robskillington/fb82ee5c737b79a3bc891df3dce7a9aa .

Unfortunately Prometheus remote_write protocol isn't the easiest protocol to implement and debug in Python. There are other time series databases, which accept data via much simpler text-based protocols such as [Influx line protocol](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/write_protocols/line_protocol_tutorial/), [Graphite plaintext protocol](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/feeding-carbon.html#the-plaintext-protocol), [OpenTSDB put protocol](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_telnet/put.html), etc. For example, all these protocols are supported by [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). It also supports Prometheus querying API, so it can be used as drop-in replacement for Prometheus in Grafana. See [these docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#grafana-setup) for details.